# Stack in Python: print a list

Tags: python, stack

I have stack code:

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.__data = []

def empty(self):
    return len(self.__data) == 0

def size(self):
    return len(self.__data)

def push(self, x):
    self.__data.append(x)

def pop(self):
    return self.__data.pop()
```

and adds numbers 1, 2:

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
```

and I don't know how to print __data list?
so that it shows 1,2 in the list?

```
[1,2]
```

Comment: As an aside, quit using double-underscore name-mangling here. You almost certainly don't mean to do that

Comment: But what are you asking? Have you tried `print(self.__data)`?

Comment: Yes, I have error: print(self.__data)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined.
that's my problem, I'm just learning

Comment: Where are you trying to do that? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Try to include as much details as possible, including what you think should work and your reasoning. Don't make people guess.

Comment: avoid using an underscore as a variable prefix inside a class unless there's a need, underscores have special meaning in python and they may cause errors if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__str__` method to print the values using `print()` or `__repr__` for direct representation.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.data) == 0

    def size(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def push(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        return self.data.pop()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)

>>> stack = Stack()
>>> stack.push(1)
>>> stack.push(2)
>>> print(stack)  ## using __str__
# [1, 2]
>>> stack         ## using __repr__
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

As `__data` is a private attribute of stack object, it cannot be accessed outside the class. Instead define an instance method to print the stack list as shown below.

```
class Stack:
    def print_stack(self):
        print(self.__data)
```

Now if you call `print_stack()` on an instance. It will print the `__data` list.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more question. My code:

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = []

def empty(self):
    return len(self.data) == 0

def size(self):
    return len(self.data)

def push(self, x):
    self.data.append(x)

def pop(self):
    if len(self.data) == 0:
        print("underflow")
    else:
        return self.data.pop()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)

stack = Stack()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
print(stack)
```

I print the list as I wanted:

> [1,2]

Now i wonder if i can work on this list? That is, as always on the lists:
In this case:

```
list = stack
list[0]
```

> 1

Can you recommend some simple courses where do Class is explained? I feel confused and my questions seem simple...

Comment: Now, I have error: 'Stack' object is not subscriptable